# How to select all options with Autocomplete component from material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Can I add a `select all` option to select all options with the `Autocomplete` component from material-ui?

I added `{ title: "Select All", value: true },` in `top100Films` array.

But I also could manually add space between the dropdown and TextField and have a button there.

But either way, how can I grab all options?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";
import CheckBoxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckBox";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </li>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "Select All", value: true },
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
    year: 2003
  },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
    year: 2001
  },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
    year: 1980
  },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
    year: 2002
  },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
    year: 1977
  },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 }
];
```

You can get a demo [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#checkboxes) and add `{ title: "Select All", value: true },` in `top100Films` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sharing the cleanest solution that I could come up with, and keeping all logic inside the Autocomplete component.

First thing, I mixed up the exemples of [checkboxes](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#system-CheckboxesTags.js) and [controlled states](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#system-ControllableStates.js)

And I got this:

```
export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => { setValue(newValue); }}
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </li>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Then I made 3 modifications: `onChange`, `renderOption` and add `filterOptions`.

```
export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      value={value}
      filterOptions={(options, params) => { // <<<--- inject the Select All option
        const filter = createFilterOptions()
        const filtered = filter(options, params)
        return [{ title: 'Select All...', all: true }, ...filtered]
      }}
      // onChange={(event, newValue) => { setValue(newValue); }} <<<--- OLD
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        if (newValue.find(option => option.all))
          return setValue(value.length === top100Films.length ? [] : top100Films)
  
          setValue(newValue)
      }}
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            // checked={selected} <<<--- OLD
            checked={option.all ? !!(value.length === top100Films.length) : selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </li>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

And that is it!

Working demo here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grkosu?file=Demo.js

Answer (score 8):

Found another interesting (as it seems to me) way. A little more simple, not counting a couple of tricks =) Not sure if it's correct, but flexible enough and it was fun to make it.

In short: thanks to the [PaperComponent](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) prop, we can change the "dropdown" list component (hence, inject other components into it).

So instead of making the "select all" checkbox a list item, we can implement it separately in Popper.

The trick I mentioned is that you will need to manually use event.preventDefault() on the onClick and onMouseDown events (which is what the default Autocomplete internals do).

My example:

[image: Edit materia UI Autocomplete Select All action]

Code:

```
import { FC, useState } from "react";

import {
  TextField,
  Autocomplete,
  Box,
  Paper,
  Checkbox,
  FormControlLabel,
  Divider
} from "@mui/material";

const allOptions = [
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "var",
  "let",
  "fiz",
  "baz",
  "int",
  "str",
  "big",
  "dog",
  "cat"
] as const;

type Option = typeof allOptions[number];

export const AutocompleteWithSelectAll: FC = () => {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState<Option[]>([]);
  const [selectAll, setSelectAll] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleToggleSelectAll = () => {
    setSelectAll((prev) => {
      if (!prev) setColumns([...allOptions]);
      else setColumns([]);
      return !prev;
    });
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id={"autocomplete_with_select_all"}
      multiple
      options={allOptions}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      filterSelectedOptions
      freeSolo={false}
      value={columns}
      onChange={(_e, value, reason) => {
        if (reason === "clear" || reason === "removeOption")
          setSelectAll(false);
        if (reason === "selectOption" && value.length === allOptions.length)
          setSelectAll(true);
        setColumns(value);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={"Click me!"} />}
      PaperComponent={(paperProps) => {
        const { children, ...restPaperProps } = paperProps;
        return (
          <Paper {...restPaperProps}>
            <Box
              onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()} // prevent blur
              pl={1.5}
              py={0.5}
            >
              <FormControlLabel
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault(); // prevent blur
                  handleToggleSelectAll();
                }}
                label="Select all"
                control={
                  <Checkbox id="select-all-checkbox" checked={selectAll} />
                }
              />
            </Box>
            <Divider />
            {children}
          </Paper>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AutocompleteWithSelectAll;
```

Comment: These examples are great. I noticed that when you select an item from the bottom of the list, then the entire list scrolls to the top. Can that be prevented?

Comment: I tried to look for a solution to the problem, but it turned out to be not so trivial. A very similar problem is described here in [github issues](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30249), but the solutions suggested there did not help. Also in this [example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30249) from the documentation, if you add props `filterSelectedOptions` to Autocomplete (which changes the state of the list of options on each select), the same problem is observed. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to avoid this behavior in my example :(

Comment: Also, even if we look at the answer of [Amr Eraky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74456825/17396945), yes, the situation is better there. But, if you scroll down from the very beginning, select the last option, and then deselect, this behavior is again observed. More like an issue with Autocomplete itself, although I could be wrong.

Comment: you can resolve the scroll issue by using the useMemo. 

const customPaperComponent=(paperProps) => { .....here goes the code in paper component.... }
 const customPaper = useMemo(() => customPaperComponent, []);
and in your autocomplete replace the paper component with the following
 PaperComponent={customPaper}

Answer (score 3):

- You have to:
  1- handle `onChange` event if `Select All` is selected.
  2- handle `renderOption` property to handle `Checkbox` if `Select All` is selected.

Example:

[image: Edit geocoding-demo (forked)]

Comment: It has to be `Autocomplete` component not `MultiSelect`. and it seems like `Autocomplete` doesn't offer `selectAllLabel` property.

Comment: `Autocomplete ` don't have `selectAllLabel` ! It's passed prop from parent component in the Demo example. But you can replace `selectAllLabel` with any label `string` you want !!!
return [{ label: 'Select all', value: "select-all" }, ...filtered];`

Answer (score 1):

I simplified it as below to save myself from the re-rendering effect on option selection at the list end while using paperComponent/PopperComponent.

```
        renderOption={(props, option: SchoolValue, { selected }) => (
          option?.id === 'all' ? (
            <>
              <Box sx={{ ...styles.box } as SxProps}>
                <Checkbox
                  checked={checkAll}
                  onChange={checkAllChange}
                  id="check-all"
                  onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                />
                All Schools
              </Box>
              <Divider />
            </>
          ) : (
            <Box component="li" {...props}>
              <Checkbox
                color={'primary' as  CheckboxProps['color']}
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                checked={selected}
                sx={{ mr: '8px' }}
              />
              {`${option?.name ?? ''}`}
            </Box>
          )
        )}
```